# Migrating app from Rails 2 to Rails3: map.redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an app written for Rails 2 that I am trying to get running under rails3 but am failing at the first hurdle,the routes table.  What I currently have is the following:

```
map.redirect ':shortened', :controller => 'items', :action => 'redirect', :conditions => {:method => :get}
```

map.shorten  '',           :controller => 'items', :action => 'shorten'

but I am trying to 'translate' this for rails3 - is there an equivalent to the above that would work?

many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your redirect route see here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#redirection

For your second route you can simply do `match '/shorten/' => 'items#shorten'`

Comment: for the second, absolutely spot on, thanks a lot - for the first hacking around and this looks right but isn't quite: match "/:shortened" => redirect(:conditions => "/#:method => :get}")

Comment: Im not a 100% clear on what you want the redirect to do?  Give this a try `match '/shortened' => redirect('/items/redirect/'), :constraints => {:method => "get"}`

Comment: i think thats pretty much it Austin, i think that other issues in the migration to rails3 are the reason why its not working - many thanks